How can we check the amplness of a normal bundle?
Let $P^{n^2-1}$ be a projective space of n by n matrices. And let $Y\subset P^{n^2-1}$ be a projective variety defined by the $(n-1)\times (n-1)$ minors. Hence $Y$ parametrizes the rank $(n-2)$ locus. And $X$ be a hypersurface defined by the (sufficiently generic)linear combination of $(n-1)\times (n-1)$ minors. Is $Y\subset X$ has an ample normal bundle? How can we check that? Also, suppose that $L$ is a $3$-dimensional linear space contained in $X$. Is $L\subset X$ also has an ample normal bundle?
